# Evaluate integral using Cauchy's integral for derivatives.

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula

> Integrate counterclockwise around the unit circle.

$$\int_c \frac{e^{z}}{z^{n}}dz$$ where n = 1,2,...

Where do I even begin this?

I know the integral formula that I probably want to use is:

$$\int \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz = \frac{2\pi \cdot i}{n!} \cdot f^{n}(a)$$

Is the answer just going to be in general form?

So $e^{z}$ derivatives are  just $e^{z}$. What should I do with z? Do I have to convert it?

Answer (score 1):

That's it!

$$\oint_C \frac{e^z}{z^n} dz = \frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!} \left. \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1} }e^z \right |_{z=0}$$

$$\oint_C \frac{e^z}{z^n} dz = \frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}$$

Another way $\cdots$

$$\oint_C \frac{e^z}{z^n} dz = \oint \frac{dz}{z^n}\left[1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots \right]=2\pi i\oint \frac{dz}{z^n}\frac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\frac{2\pi i} {(n-1)!},$$  since all other terms evaluate to zero.

Comment: The last term on the first row is just the nth - 1 derivative of $e^{z}$ correct?

Comment: Yes, the $(n-1)^\text{th}$ derivative evaluated at $z=0.$

Comment: $f(z)=e^z$, $f^{(n-1)}(z)=e^z$,  $f^{(n-1)}(0)=e^0=1.$